# How to get images from google RSS feed?

Tags: xml, rss, google-news

I'm using Google RSS for showing feed on my website.

RSS LINK :[Google RSS Link](https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=cars)

Output XML looks like this:
[XML Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXxGl.png)

Google News Output looks like this:
[Google News Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xITzG.png)

In the Google Webpage, I can see the image thumbnail for the same RSS feed.
But in the XML, I can't able to find image thumbnail.

**Thus anyone knows how to get an image thumbnail from Google News RSS XML.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't find a solution, consider use "newsapi" - [as I shown in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63491563/4092887).

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The images do not come from the RSS feed but actually the metadata from the article link.

I do not know the exact method that Google New uses. But my guess is that Google News uses link preview to grab the image for the article. This is done by fetching the article page and extracting the metadata such as:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
```

I used [LinkFork](https://linkfork.co) link preview to verify that the images from Google News matches with the article.