# How can I select the date range in Google News RSS feed or create RSS feed with date range from Google Search?

Tags: rss, google-search, google-news

I'd like to create a RSS feed for Google News results by specific date ranges and keywords for a data mining paper with R, but struggeling to get the date range in an RSS feed.

**Option1: Date range missing:**
In am able to create the google news rss feed with my search terms "corona" and "nameofnewspaper", however I am only able to select the past X days (here past 150 days: when%3A150d), not a specific range:
https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=corona%20%22supplychaindigital%22%20when%3A150d&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen

**Option2: RSS feed with date range missing:**
Eventhough in the google search under "news" and tools, I am able to select the date range, I am struggeling to convert the below link into an RSS feed, as under the create alert option besides being able to deliver to RSS feed, I cannot find an option to select the date range (so only new newsarticle appear).
https://www.google.com/search?biw=1440&bih=821&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2%2F1%2F2020%2Ccd_max%3A4%2F30%2F2020&tbm=nws&sxsrf=ALeKk010FiyrQr8gLE8tNT0L_whYBj8kTA%3A1597216127002&ei=fpUzX6mmPMqckgXPhIGoDg&q=corona+supplychaindigital.com+&oq=corona+supplychaindigital.com+&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9626.9626.0.10010.1.1.0.0.0.0.84.84.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.86vAiNLAf0E

Do you know of any other option to obtain both RSS feed and date range?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Best,
Vivi

Answer (score -1):

An option is: [newsapi.org](https://newsapi.org/)

The following URL request search articles mentioning "`xbox`" from date range "`2020-08-01` to `2020-08-03`":

```
http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=xbox&from=2020-08-01&to=2020-08-03&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=[API_KEY]
```

And these are the first 20 results:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 1746,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Theinventory.com"
            },
            "author": "The Inventory Staff on Kinja Deals, shared by Elizabeth Henges to Lifehacker",
            "title": "Sunday's Best Deals: Right Angle Clamps, Bath Towels, John Wick, Packs of Masks, and More",
            "description": "A deal on John Wick 4K Blu-Rays, Tie Bar’s 5 packs of masks, a deal on a fight stick, bathroom towels for $30, and more are some of Sunday’s best deals.Read more...",
            "url": "https://kinjadeals.theinventory.com/sundays-best-deals-right-angle-clamps-bath-towels-jo-1844585414",
            "urlToImage": "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,fl_progressive,g_center,h_675,pg_1,q_80,w_1200/djgb7gtjehmfjzytbef1.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-02T14:40:00Z",
            "content": "A deal on John Wick 4K Blu-Rays, Tie Bars 5 packs of masks, a deal on a fight stick, bathroom towels for $30, and more are some of Sundays best deals.\r\nBookmark Kinja Deals and follow us on Twitter t… [+35497 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "engadget",
                "name": "Engadget"
            },
            "author": "Jon Fingas",
            "title": "Classic 'Halo' games will get crossplay and custom game browsing in 2020",
            "description": "The Halo games in the Master Chief Collection should soon get many of the features you’re used to with modern shooters. The 343 Industries team has provided (via Eurogamer) an MCC “snapshot” indicating that several welcome additions are coming to the classic …",
            "url": "https://www.engadget.com/halo-master-chief-collection-crossplay-2020-212636400.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://o.aolcdn.com/images/dims?resize=1200%2C630&crop=1200%2C630%2C0%2C0&quality=95&image_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs.yimg.com%2Fos%2Fcreatr-uploaded-images%2F2020-08%2Fe7b52340-d4f7-11ea-9f73-cf1f814f40a2&client=amp-blogside-v2&signature=346daafa2e86ec849f8c4a7f24e8a6b492af6ee8",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-02T21:26:36Z",
            "content": "The Halo games in the Master Chief Collection should soon get many of the features you’re used to with modern shooters. The 343 Industries team has provided (via Eurogamer) an MCC “snapshot” indicati… [+609 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "engadget",
                "name": "Engadget"
            },
            "author": "Igor Bonifacic",
            "title": "Spider-Man is coming to the PlayStation version of 'Marvel's Avengers'",
            "description": "Marvel's Avengers on Sony platforms will feature an exclusive hero: Spider-Man. Developer Crystal Dynamics said it plans to add the superhero to the PlayStation version of the upcoming game in early 2021. The studio didn't say whether Spider-Man will make his…",
            "url": "https://www.engadget.com/spider-man-marvels-avengers-190545589.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://o.aolcdn.com/images/dims?resize=1200%2C630&crop=1200%2C630%2C0%2C0&quality=95&image_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs.yimg.com%2Fos%2Fcreatr-uploaded-images%2F2020-08%2F9ba08af0-d5b8-11ea-bffa-efbdb30617c0&client=amp-blogside-v2&signature=896162a760da4142c0ef09eb4012101329437ed0",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T19:05:45Z",
            "content": "It's not too surprising to find out Spider-Man is only coming to PlayStation. After all, Sony recently published an exclusive featuring Peter Parker and is working on a standalone title starring Mile… [+587 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "engadget",
                "name": "Engadget"
            },
            "author": "Mariella Moon",
            "title": "Netflix is making a film based on Ubisoft's 'Beyond Good & Evil'",
            "description": "Netflix is working on a feature film adaptation of Ubisoft’s Beyond Good & Evil, the streaming platform has revealed on Twitter. According to The Hollywood Reporter, the project is still in early development and still in in the midst of looking for writers. I…",
            "url": "https://www.engadget.com/beyond-good-and-evil-movie-070207377.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://o.aolcdn.com/images/dims?resize=1200%2C630&crop=1200%2C630%2C0%2C0&quality=95&image_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs.yimg.com%2Fos%2Fcreatr-uploaded-images%2F2020-08%2F833e5280-d39c-11ea-9af3-f172f82ea909&client=amp-blogside-v2&signature=541ba6f91ec2771f202dfdf36f56132f213c5da2",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-01T07:02:07Z",
            "content": "Netflix is working on a feature film adaptation of Ubisoft’s Beyond Good &amp; Evil, the streaming platform has revealed on Twitter. According to The Hollywood Reporter, the project is still in early… [+1059 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "reuters",
                "name": "Reuters"
            },
            "author": "Reuters Editorial",
            "title": "Take-Two raises sales forecast as videogames get stay-at-home boost - Reuters UK",
            "description": "Take-Two Interactive Software Inc on Monday raised its fiscal year adjusted sales forecast after beating quarterly estimates on demand for its videogame franchises \"Grand Theft Auto\" and \"NBA 2K\" from people stuck at home due to lockdowns.",
            "url": "https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-take-two-results-idUKKCN24Z2R5",
            "urlToImage": "https://s4.reutersmedia.net/resources_v2/images/rcom-default.png",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T22:43:00Z",
            "content": "(Reuters) - Take-Two Interactive Software Inc (TTWO.O) on Monday raised its fiscal year adjusted sales forecast after beating quarterly estimates on demand for its videogame franchises “Grand Theft A… [+1734 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Android Central"
            },
            "author": "Samuel Tolbert",
            "title": "Spider-Man swings into Marvel's Avengers in 2021 — but only on PS5 and PS4",
            "description": "Your friendly neighborhood hero isn't coming to all platforms.\n\nWhat you need to know\n\n\nMarvel's Avengers will have heroes added post-launch for free.\nSpider-Man is joining the roster in 2021, exclusively on PS4 and PS5.\nMarvel's Avengers is set to release on…",
            "url": "https://www.androidcentral.com/spider-man-marvels-avengers-exclusive-ps4-ps5-2021",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/large/public/article_images/2020/08/marvels-avengers-spidey.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T17:24:53Z",
            "content": "PlayStation has the marketing deal for the upcoming Marvel's Avengers but there's even more to the partnership. Today, Square Enix and Crystal Dynamics revealed via PlayStation Blog that Spider-Man i… [+927 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Android Central"
            },
            "author": "Samuel Tolbert",
            "title": "Monster Hunter World has now sold over 16 million copies",
            "description": "An absolute behemoth that keeps on going.\n\nWhat you need to know\n\n\nCapcom has shared its financial results for Q1 of fiscal year 2021.\nMonster Hunter World has now sold over 16 million copies sold.\nResident Evil 3 has crossed 2.7 million copies sold.\n\n\nLike s…",
            "url": "https://www.androidcentral.com/monster-hunter-world-sold-16-million-copies-capcom-q1-results",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/large/public/field/image/2020/01/monster_hunter_world_iceborne_barioth-b73h.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T22:25:49Z",
            "content": "Like so many other companies over the last week, Capcom has shared its results for Q1 of fiscal year 2021, ending June 30, 2020. Monster Hunter World: Iceborne is continuing to sell extremely well an… [+584 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Android Central"
            },
            "author": "Samuel Tolbert",
            "title": "Grand Theft Auto V has sold almost 135 million copies",
            "description": "If you think this game doesn't have life left in it, think again.\n\nWhat you need to know\n\n\nTake-Two Interactive has posted its financial results for Q1 of financial year 2021.\nGrand Theft Auto V has now sold almost 135 million copies.\nBorderlands 3 has crosse…",
            "url": "https://www.androidcentral.com/take-two-interactive-q1-results-gta-v-135-million",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/large/public/field/image/2020/08/grand-theft-auto-v-promo-image-2-703w.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T21:24:37Z",
            "content": "Take-Two Interactive has shared its Q1 results for the 2021 fiscal year. Net bookings for the quarter totalled $996.2 million, which is up 136% year-over-year. Game sales remain strong overall as rep… [+1139 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Android Central"
            },
            "author": "John Levite",
            "title": "Grab a budget 4K TV with Vizio's 50-inch smart TV on sale for $290",
            "description": "The Vizio V505-H19 50-inch 4K smart TV has dropped to $289.99 at Costco. This is Vizio's 2020 entry-level 4K TV, so it's already down to as low a price as is possible for a TV like this. That price is usually $300, though, and right now Costco is giving you a…",
            "url": "https://www.androidcentral.com/grab-budget-4k-tv-vizios-50-inch-smart-tv-sale-290",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/large/public/article_images/2020/08/vizio-50-inch.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T12:49:24Z",
            "content": "The Vizio V505-H19 50-inch 4K smart TV has dropped to $289.99 at Costco. This is Vizio's 2020 entry-level 4K TV, so it's already down to as low a price as is possible for a TV like this. That price i… [+2075 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Theguardian.comgames"
            },
            "author": "Simon Parkin",
            "title": "Carrion review – flesh-eating fun",
            "description": "(Phobia Game Studio/Devolver; Switch, PC and Xbox One)Inspired by a 1950s sci-fi horror movie, Carrion turns you into a malign marauding blob, swallowing scientists wholeCarrion borrows the premise of Irvin Yeaworth’s 1958 science fiction horror film The Blob…",
            "url": "https://amp.theguardian.comgames/2020/aug/01/carrion-review-flesh-eating-fun",
            "urlToImage": "https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/462e2e8b586b8ca5901111a95cc126f007d98843/60_0_1800_1080/master/1800.jpg?width=1200&height=630&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&overlay-align=bottom%2Cleft&overlay-width=100p&overlay-base64=L2ltZy9zdGF0aWMvb3ZlcmxheXMvdGctcmV2aWV3LTQucG5n&enable=upscale&s=0baafe079acbb37fb9805c4a3915f4cf",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-01T12:00:42Z",
            "content": "Carrion borrows the premise of Irvin Yeaworths 1958 science fiction horror film The Blob, in which a young Steve McQueen takes on a corrosive, human-gobbling alien biomass, but casts you in the role … [+2183 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "business-insider",
                "name": "Business Insider"
            },
            "author": "Palmer Haasch",
            "title": "TikTok users are heaping praise on Microsoft after news broke that the company is in talks to buy the app",
            "description": "<ul>\n<li>President Trump told reporters on July 31 that he was planning on banning TikTok in the United States, causing concern among many of the app's users and influencers. </li>\n<li>TikTok was not banned over the weekend, and Microsoft has confirmed that i…",
            "url": "https://www.businessinsider.com/tiktok-ban-trump-microsoft-acquisition-making-memes-stanning-2020-8",
            "urlToImage": "https://i.insider.com/5f2846e04e52b715b01f02cf?width=1200&format=jpeg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T19:01:42Z",
            "content": "TikTok was sent into a tizzy after President Trump told reporters late Friday night on Air Force One that he was planning on banning TikTok in the United States. Three days later, TikTok is still run… [+2741 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "VG247"
            },
            "author": "Cian Maher",
            "title": "Craig the Brute is the “official Xbox mascot,” says Phil Spencer - VG247",
            "description": "<ol><li>Craig the Brute is the “official Xbox mascot,” says Phil Spencer  VG247\r\n</li><li>Craig the Brute is ‘official Xbox mascot’, as Xbox Game Pass rebranded  Metro.co.uk\r\n</li><li>Halo Infinite multiplayer will be free-to-play  GamesIndustry.biz\r\n</li><li…",
            "url": "https://www.vg247.com/2020/08/02/craig-the-brute-xbox-mascot/",
            "urlToImage": "https://assets.vg247.com/current//2020/07/craig-the-brute.png",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-02T17:35:27Z",
            "content": "If you know anything at all about Halo Infinite, you’ll probably know that every Halo fan on the planet loves Craig the Brute.\r\nWhat’s that? You don’t know Craig? That’s okay, I’ve posted a photo of … [+2049 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Push Square"
            },
            "author": "Push Square",
            "title": "More Rumours of 'Major' Third Party PS5 Exclusives Return - Push Square",
            "description": "<ol><li>More Rumours of 'Major' Third Party PS5 Exclusives Return  Push Square\r\n</li><li>All PS5 and Xbox Series X games that support 120fps  Eurogamer.net\r\n</li><li>Xbox Series X games are OFF THE CHAIN – Microsoft's Matt Booty explains how  T3\r\n</li><li>PS5…",
            "url": "https://www.pushsquare.com/news/2020/08/more_rumours_of_major_third_party_ps5_exclusives_return",
            "urlToImage": "https://images.pushsquare.com/e359e7c9f632d/1280x720.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-01T19:30:00Z",
            "content": "Rumours have been flying around for a while with regards to Sony tying down significant deals with third party publishers. Whispers say that the Japanese giant has secured a number of major franchise… [+1816 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Push Square"
            },
            "author": "Push Square",
            "title": "PS5 Fans Hyped After Sony Updates Future of Gaming Playlist - Push Square",
            "description": "<ol><li>PS5 Fans Hyped After Sony Updates Future of Gaming Playlist  Push Square\r\n</li><li>PS5: Sony's New Tv's Are Finally Here!  TheGamer\r\n</li><li>All PS5 and Xbox Series X games that support 120fps  Eurogamer.net\r\n</li><li>Leaker Reveals When PS5 and Xbox…",
            "url": "https://www.pushsquare.com/news/2020/08/ps5_fans_hyped_after_sony_updates_future_of_gaming_playlist",
            "urlToImage": "https://images.pushsquare.com/16fc29ebad24a/1280x720.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-01T15:30:00Z",
            "content": "Sony has updated its Future of Gaming playlist on YouTube, which compiled all of the announcements from its recent PlayStation 5 reveal event. This could be the first hint that fresh news is on the w… [+570 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "About Chromebooks"
            },
            "author": "Kevin C. Tofel",
            "title": "Bought a Chromebook released after July 2017? You've got Stadia Pro free for three months - About Chromebooks",
            "description": "<ol><li>Bought a Chromebook released after July 2017? You've got Stadia Pro free for three months  About Chromebooks\r\n</li><li>Chromebook owners can claim a free three-month Stadia Pro trial now  MobileSyrup\r\n</li><li>Not Dead Yet: Google Stadia 2020 Review &…",
            "url": "https://www.aboutchromebooks.com/news/bought-a-chromebook-released-after-july-2017-youve-got-stadia-pro-free-for-three-months/",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.aboutchromebooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/stadia-pro-perk.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-02T19:27:00Z",
            "content": "Another week brings another perk to Chromebooks, following on last weeks deal for 100 GB of Dropbox storage. This week you can snag three free months of Stadia Pro, which is a value of $29.97 at the … [+3340 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Metro.co.uk"
            },
            "author": "GameCentral",
            "title": "Games Inbox: Will Sony make PS5 online free? - Metro.co.uk",
            "description": "<ol><li>Games Inbox: Will Sony make PS5 online free?  Metro.co.uk\r\n</li><li>Xbox Series X SHOCK tactic does the unthinkable - leaves PS5 in the dust  T3\r\n</li><li>The Best PS4 Games of All Time  IGN Africa\r\n</li><li>Guide: New PS4 Games This Week (3rd August …",
            "url": "https://metro.co.uk/2020/08/03/games-inbox-ps5-online-free-keeping-fit-video-games-lego-nes-kids-13073746/",
            "urlToImage": "https://i2.wp.com/metro.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/sony_psn_logo-e1420448700237_1596400283.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&w=1200&h=630&crop=1&zoom=1&ssl=1",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T00:00:00Z",
            "content": "Could Microsoft force it to become free? (pic: Sony)\r\nThe Monday Inbox asks whether loading times are the next gen killer app, as the Sega Saturn gets compared to the Xbox Series X and PS5.\r\nTo join … [+14501 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Tom's Guide"
            },
            "author": "Mark Spoonauer",
            "title": "How to watch Samsung Unpacked: Galaxy Note 20, Galaxy Watch 3, Galaxy Buds Live and more - Tom's Guide UK",
            "description": "<ol><li>How to watch Samsung Unpacked: Galaxy Note 20, Galaxy Watch 3, Galaxy Buds Live and more  Tom's Guide UK\r\n</li><li>The Huawei Mate Xs is still the best foldable phone you can buy, but it's not perfect  TechRadar\r\n</li><li>Leaked Galaxy Note 20 5G, Not…",
            "url": "https://www.tomsguide.com/news/how-to-watch-samsung-unpacked-galaxy-note-20-galaxy-watch-3-galaxy-buds-live-and-more",
            "urlToImage": "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/wMMZxCh54neQEZsof4AxE6-1200-80.jpeg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T05:00:00Z",
            "content": "After months of speculation — and lots and lots of leaks — Samsung is finally ready to take the wraps off of the Galaxy Note 20 along with four other devices.\r\nSamsung has said that it will be showin… [+4370 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "ReadWrite"
            },
            "author": "Saurabh Hooda",
            "title": "10 Best Artificial Intelligence Software",
            "description": "Progressive utilization of Artificial Intelligence software in the market for computerization of the procedures, programming, and other purposes has become common. AI-based platforms feature profound machine calculations and learning for robotizing business p…",
            "url": "https://readwrite.com/2020/08/03/10-best-artificial-intelligence-software/",
            "urlToImage": "https://images.readwrite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/10-Best-Artificial-Intelligence-Software.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T15:00:24Z",
            "content": "Progressive utilization of Artificial Intelligence software in the market for computerization of the procedures, programming, and other purposes has become common. AI-based platforms feature profound… [+12831 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Kotaku"
            },
            "author": "Riley MacLeod",
            "title": "The Week In Games: Fall Guys Horizons",
            "description": "We’re in a bit of the summer doldrums for big games, but there’s still plenty to get excited about. Fall Guys comes to PS4 and PC this week. There’s a Fast & Furious game. And Horizon Zero Dawn makes its PC debut. Read more...",
            "url": "https://kotaku.com/the-week-in-games-fall-guys-horizons-1844587781",
            "urlToImage": "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,fl_progressive,g_center,h_675,pg_1,q_80,w_1200/knsjyjakx5jwz0upgl4n.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-02T21:16:00Z",
            "content": "Were in a bit of the summer doldrums for big games, but theres still plenty to get excited about. Fall Guys comes to PS4 and PC this week. Theres a Fast &amp; Furious game. And Horizon Zero Dawn make… [+1368 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Kotaku"
            },
            "author": "S.E. Doster",
            "title": "Call Of Duty Is Finally Blowing The Top Off The Warzone Stadium",
            "description": "Warzone’s stadium explosion was officially revealed with today’s Call of Duty: Modern Warfare trailer. The teased event will finally come to fruition with Season 5, which kicks off on August 5 across PlayStation 4, Xbox One, and PC.Read more...",
            "url": "https://kotaku.com/call-of-duty-is-finally-blowing-the-top-off-the-warzone-1844596249",
            "urlToImage": "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,fl_progressive,g_center,h_675,pg_1,q_80,w_1200/mdrhaqrxmxilgwghjeuq.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-03T23:00:00Z",
            "content": "Warzones stadium explosion was officially revealed with todays Call of Duty: Modern Warfare trailer. The teased event will finally come to fruition with Season 5, which kicks off on August 5 across P… [+1473 chars]"
        }
    ]
}
```